# How to find the maximum number of occurrence of the values in excel?

Tags: excel

Here is my sample data. How can I find how many duplicates of each value is there? Next, I want to draw barchart for each of these values.

```
ProducerID = 1979
ProducerID = 1984
ProducerID = 1979
ProducerID = 1984
ProducerID = 1979
ProducerID = 1984
ProducerID = 1979
ProducerID = 1984
ProducerID = 1979
ProducerID = 1984
ProducerID = 1979
ProducerID = 1984
```

Answer (score 1):

There is several different ways to do this. The easiest would probably be to use the `COUNTIF()` function. `= COUNTIF(A1:A12,"ProducerID = 1979"), returns 6` for the data that you listed. For making the bar graph, you would just use the data from the `COUNTIF()` values.

More info on `COUNTIF()` is [here.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can go through this link. 
It contains all possible ways.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-count-values-in-a-worksheet-81335b1b-d5e8-4f42-ae72-245b948c45bd